# flex direction + content expanding issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, slidetoggle

Have a problem with expand content in flex element with flex-direction:colmn-reverse.

Expand works properly if parent element close to the center of window, the toggled element does`t move content over him.
But when top of this element hiding in overflow, the toggled element move content over him to top.
If property flex-direction:column, all works fine.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pavelbush/o9qcnjvg/

```
<div class="wraper">
    <div class="side left-side">
        <h3>right-side</h3>
        <div class="img"><img src="https://files.adme.ru/files/news/part_207/2077015/preview-4266215-1200x630-99-1556793614.jpg"></div>
        <div class="content">other content...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="side right-side">
        <h3>left-side</h3>
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="toggler">
                <div class="title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="text" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="toggler">
                <div class="title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="text" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="toggler">
                <div class="title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="text" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
            </div> 
            <div class="toggler">
                <div class="title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="text" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="toggler">
                <div class="title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="text" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="toggler">
                <div class="title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="text" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
            </div> 
            <div class="toggler">
                <div class="title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="text" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="toggler">
                <div class="title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="text" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="toggler">
                <div class="title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="text" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="expander">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
<script>
$('.toggler .title').on('click',function(){
    $(this).next('.text').slideToggle(300);
});
</script>
<style>
.wraper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column-reverse;
}
.title {
  padding:10px;
  background:#f2f2f2;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.side {
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.text {
  padding: 10px;
  width:150px;
}
.img {
  width:200px;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does`t work. I think the best way is refuse flex property and use jquery to change direction =/

Comment: I guess so untill flex allows this easily